# moveToThread vs deriving from QThread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

When should `moveToThread` be preferred over subclassing `QThread`?

[This link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html) shows that both methods work. On what basis should I decide what to use from those two?

Comment: [here](https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html) is good explanation about it.

Comment: this article is just an opinion. There is no explanation why, on other hand [You’re doing it wrong…](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) explains what is the problem and it is written by someone who is developing Qt. Basically I wouldn't trust first article (internet is full of crap).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would focus on the differences between the two methods. There isn't a general answer that fits all use cases, so it's good to understand exactly what they are to choose the best that fits your case.

## Using moveToThread()

*moveToThread()* is used to control the **object's thread affinity**, which basically means setting the thread (or better the Qt event loop) from which the object will emit signals and its slots will be executed.

As shown in the documentation you linked, this can be used to run code on a different thread, basically creating a **dummy worker**, writing the code to run in a **public slot** (in the example the *doWork()* slot) and then using **moveToThread** to move it to a different event loop.

Then, a signal connected to that slot is fired. Since the object that emits the signal (the *Controller* in the example) lives in a different thread, and the signal is connected to our doWork method with a queued connection, the doWork method will be executed in the worker thread.

The key here is that you are creating a **new event loop**, run by the worker thread. Hence, once the doWork slot has started, the whole event loop will be busy until it exits, and this means that incoming signals will be queued.

## Subclassing QThread()

The other method described in Qt's documentation is subclassing QThread. In this case, one overrides the default implementation of the QThread::run() method, which creates an event loop, to run something else.

There's nothing wrong with this approach itself, although there are several catches.

First of all, it is very easy to write unsafe code, because the *run()* method is the only one in that class that will be actually run on another thread.

If as an example, you have a member variable that you initialize in the constructor and then use in the *run()* method, your member is initialized in the thread of the caller and then used in the new thread.

Same story for any public method that could be called either from the caller or inside run().

Also slots would be executed from the caller's thread, (unless you do something really weird as *moveToThread(this)*) leading to extra confusion.

So, it is possible, but you really are on your own with this approach and you must pay extra attention.

## Other approaches

There are of course alternatives to both approaches, depending on what you need. If you just need to run some code in background while your GUI thread is running you may consider using [QtConcurrent::run()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run).

However, keep in mind that QtConcurrent will use the global *QThreadPool*. If the whole pool is busy (meaning there aren't available threads in the pool), your code will not run immediately.

Another alternative, if you are at the least on C++11, is to use a lower level API such as [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Answer (score 12):

As a starting point: use neither. In most cases, you have a unit of work that you wish to run asynchronously. Use [`QtConcurrent::run`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) for that.

If you have an object that reacts to events and/or uses timers, it's a `QObject` that should be non-blocking and go in a thread, perhaps shared with other objects.

Such an object can also wrap blocking APIs.

Subclassing `QThread` is never necessary in practice. It's like subclassing `QFile`. `QThread` is a thread handle. It wraps a system resource. Overloading it is a bit silly.

Comment: `Subclassing QThread is never necessary in practice.` If I don't make a subclass of QThread then what would be the way to redefine run() function?

Comment: There's no need for it - not usually. The stuff to be done can be just a regular function submitted to `QtConcurrent::run`, or a timer handler on an object, etc.

Comment: You haven't talked about "movetothread". In what cases should that be preferred? Subclassing qthread and movetothread both require writing a new class.

Comment: An object that you move to a thread will have, presumably, lots of functionality. All of it would belong to a separate class anyway. If it doesn't, then write a freestanding function or a lambda to be submitted to `QtConcurrent::run`. Subclassing `QThread` is never a solution, since it's an absolutely weird object. It resides in the wrong thread. It's not meant to be subclassed while also adding slots to it, etc.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl moveToThread is used to determite QObject thread affinity. If you have class emitting signals and receiving slots which should work in different thread that is the case to use moveToThread, because calling slots in different threads work different from the same thread.

Comment: @Jeka A `QObject`'s thread never matters when emitting the signals. The current thread is used instead.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer is ALWAYS.
When you move object to thread:

- it is easy to write test for code
- it is easy to refactor code (you can use thread but you don't have to).
- you do not mix functionality of thread with business logic
- there is no problem with object lifetime

When you subclass `QThread`

- it is harder to write test
- object clean up process can get very confusing leading to strange errors.

There is full description of the problem from Qt blog: [You’re doing it wrong…](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

`QtConcurrent::run` is also very handy.

Please remember that by default slots are trying to jump between treads when signal is send from other thread object is assigned to. For details see documentation of [Qt::ConnectionType](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Answer (score 4):

QThread is low level thread abstraction, first look at high level API [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) module and [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html)

If nothing of these is suitable for you, then read [this old article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), it tells how you should use QThread. Think about thread and task performed in this thread as a separate objects, don't mix them together.

So, if you need to write come custom, specific or extended thread wrapper then you should subclass QThread.

If you have QObject derived class with signals and slots, then use moveToThread on it.

In other cases use QtConcurrent, QRunnable and QThreadPoll.