# Worker thread stops processing events during infinite loop in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5, signals-slots, qthread

I've created a Worker object in Qt to process video input indefinitely, and then move it into a QThread to keep the UI thread going. The problem is, I designed it such that the video capture function runs in an infinite loop until interrupted by a flag, and the flag was supposed to be set by a slot in the Worker object, but since the Worker object is inside the infinite loop, it never processes this "quit" slot (or at least I think that's what's happening). I depend on an external library so substituting the video polling for another method is not really an option. Can someone please confirm that this is indeed the problem and suggest a solution? Here's the code:

```
class worker : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    worker(QObject* parent = NULL);
    ~worker(){}
    Q_SLOT void process();
    Q_SLOT void stop();
private:
    bool quit;
};

worker::worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent){
    quit = false;
}
void worker::process(){
    while(!quit){
        //this library call puts the thread to sleep until a frame is available
        WaitForVideoFrame();
    }
}
void worker::stop(){
    quit = true;
}
```

and then from the UI object I have:

```
MyWorker = new worker();
QThread* thread = new QThread;
MyWorker->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), MyWorker, SLOT(process()));
QPushButton* stop_button = new QPushButton(this);
connect(stop_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), MyWorker, SLOT(stop()));
thread->start();
```

The problem here is that when I press the stop_button, nothing happens, the worker keeps running the loop.  Is there maybe a function that I can call to yield processing time to the event loop from within the infinite loop? Or a better design/solution for this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How long is this thread running?

Comment: It might run for an entire day, Jon. 8, 10 hours uninterrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with your assumption. Each `QThread` has it's own `QEventLoop` and when you emit the signal on different thread it will be queued in target `QEventLoop` for processing. Once `QEventLoop` of your worker is processing the event any additional emitted signals will be queued and processed after you are finished with current slot.

However it should not be too hard to fix this; it takes a bit of caution but you can safely derive from `QThread` and make this long polling work. If you don't need resumable action `QThread` even has a property that will indicate to you that the interruption has been requested - check [QThread::isInterruptionRequested()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#isInterruptionRequested), e.g.:

```
class mythread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QThread::QThread;

    void run() override { // Main loop
        while (!isInterruptionRequested()) {
           //this library call puts the thread to sleep until a frame is available
           WaitForVideoFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

However you *do* need to be bit careful about proper shutdown sequence (presumably in your MainWindow destructor):

```
void stopThread() {
    if (m_thread != nullptr) {
        m_thread->requestInterruption();
        m_thread->exit();
        m_thread->wait();
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: Sample above works with assumption that you don't need fully working signals & slots; if you do you can update `run()` method to process it while you are waiting:

```
class mythread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using QThread::QThread;

signals:
    void alive();

public slots:
    void onTimeout() { qDebug() << "timeout!"; }

    void run() override {  // Main loop
        QTimer timer;
        timer.setInterval(1500);
        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &mythread::alive);
        timer.start();

        while (!isInterruptionRequested()) {
            //this library call puts the thread to sleep until a frame is available
            WaitForVideoFrame();

            // Process event queue
            eventDispatcher()->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can hook it up in usual manner:

```
mythread t;
t.start();

QTimer timer;
timer.setInterval(1000);

QObject::connect(&t, &mythread::alive, [] {
    qDebug() << "I'm alive";
});

QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &t, &mythread::onTimeout);

timer.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, shrpq. May I ask though, how does that fit with the guideline that you are not supposed to derive from QThread to implement processing, only to add thread functionality? Will I run into some kind of problem by deriving directly from QThread?

Comment: @ArmandoMartins YES you will run into issues. The implementation above does not cause the event loop to process events, meaning queued signals and inter-thread events will never propagate. Your flag should also be atomic or protected by a mutex.

Comment: Your `mythread` implementation lacks an event loop, as the default implementation of `run` calls `exec`, which is where the event loop is started!

Comment: @ArmandoMartins It is perfectly safe and valid to subclass QThread, and never run an event loop, if you don't need Qt event processing. Cf. https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html eg. as used in Qt's mandelbrot example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html

Comment: Whoops, also true. I did not mean to imply that you should never subclass `QThread`, which has its own uses.

Comment: @JonHarper yeah, that's what this article is all about ;) And I think this problem is a good candidate for such a specialized, non-event-loop thread. (NB: isInterruptionRequested thread-safe, so no need for explicit mutex/atomic)

Comment: @king_nak His worker object uses slots, which means events. He needs an event loop running. =/ (Of course, he could refactor and just tell the thread to quit instead of the object, but he still wouldn't need to subclass QThread.)

Comment: @JonHarper Yes, 2 slots: start working, stop working. Thats coud be rewritten as entry in `run`, and return from `run`.... But that's matter of taste. I'd implement this as a QThread subclass, given the information we have

Comment: @ArmandoMartins As someone above mentioned it's OK to derive from QThread if you don't need event thread, which based on snippet you provided you don't need - your process slot can be replaced by run method directly and stop can be replaced by simple call to function. I updated the code to show how to use full signals/slots approach. There are of course other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the event dispatcher

First, here's the documentation on [QAbstractEventDispatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracteventdispatcher.html), which makes queued signals and inter-thread event propagation work.

```
thread()->eventDispatcher()->processEvents();
```

Add the line above somewhere in your loop so that it will be called at suitable intervals. It retrieves the current thread, then the thread's event dispatcher, and finally forces the dispatcher to process any pending events (which includes *incoming* queued signals).

#### Use a thread-safe method of signalling it's time to stop

Instead of using a thread-unsafe flag, you can call the owning thread's [`requestInterruption()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption) function.

Subsequently, you can call `QThread::isInterruptionRequested()`. If it returns true, you can assume it's time to stop doing whatever work you're doing.

Your loop will look something like this in the end:

```
void worker::process(){
    while(!thread->isInterruptionRequested()){
        thread()->eventDispatcher()->processEvents();
        if (thread()->isInterruptionRequested())
            break;
        WaitForVideoFrame();
    }
}
```

You have two possibly long-running calls in this loop, the call to process events and `WaitForVideoFrame()`. I've setup the loop to check if it should quit after both. The standard disclaimer applies: test this for performance in your use case (specifically, checking for an interruption request twice in the loop may be too aggressive).

#### Should you subclass QThread?

Related from comments: [moveToThread vs deriving from QThread in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622536/movetothread-vs-deriving-from-qthread-in-qt)

Comment: Thanks to all for the feedback and valuable discussion. I have decided to go with Jon Harper's suggestion as I do need the slot mechanism (I'm sending out video frames using signals), and for other things as well. But all the suggestions gave me a clear understanding of the different approaches and their uses, thanks to all!